# sql server select query one column is the same and another is different

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to be able to find occurrences in a table where one column is the same but another is different.

Example table:

```
id    team    week
1     1       1
1     2       1
2     2       1
2     1       2
```

I want a query that will find all ids where team is different yet week is still the same so something like team does not equal team, but week does equal week.

Basically I would like to know if any id changed teams in the same week, how do i do this?

Comment: What are the desired results for your example data?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, 
    t1.week
FROM 
    YourTable t1
    JOIN YourTable t2 
        ON t1.ID = t2.ID
        AND t1.team < t2.team
        AND t1.week = t2.week
```

Comment: Thank you, never occurred to me to join the table with itself.

Comment: @Richardakacyberkiwi Good point... that'll keep the same mismatch from being returned twice; updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID
, COUNT(DISTINCT TEAM) AS CNT_TEAM
, COUNT(DISTINCT WEEK) AS CNT_WEEK
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TEAM) > 1
AND COUNT(DISTINCT WEEK) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT distinct id
FROM TeamWeek
GROUP BY id, week
HAVING Count(team) > 1
```